# Distinct across different types of collection

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Here's the object graph

```
public class Dto
{
  public List<OrderTypeA> AOrders {get;set;}
  public List<OrderTypeB> BOrders {get;set;}
}
public class OrderTypeA
{
  public string PortfolioCode {get;set}
}
public class OrderTypeB
{
  public string PortfolioCode {get;set}
}
```

How do I find distinct of portfolioCode(s) from Dto object across AOrders collection and BOrders colection. Its fairly easy adding it to a list and then doing distinct on the list but is there a one liner with linq

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> distinctPortfolioCodes = dto.AOrders
    .Select(a => a.PortfolioCode)
    .Union(dto.BOrders.Select(b => b.PortfolioCode))
    .ToList();
```

When we do a Union we only get the distincts value of both OrderTypeA, and OrderTypeB.

Quick and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

```
var distinctPortfolioCodes = dto.AOrders.Select(order => order.PortfolioCode)
  .Concat(dto.BOrders.Select(order => order.PortfolioCode))
    .Distinct();
```

first create a sequence of all the portfolio codes from the **AOrders** collection.( `dto.AOrders.Select`) then concatenate( `.Concat`) this sequence with a sequence of all the portfolio codes from the **BOrders** collection. Finally, we will call the `Distinct()` method on the resulting sequence(which is now only of type `string`) to remove any duplicate

Comment: This is a good approach, I would say if the lists are very big, but otherwise I would go with Union. 
Concat.Distinct could be faster then.